# Using ng-options with option select in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS, and I want to use ng-options for a select tag to display options grouped by optgroups.

this is the array I want to use in my  select option:

```
$scope.myList = [
    {
      "codeGroupCompetence": 1,
      "titre": "TECH. DE PRODUCTION / EXPLOITATION",
      "activated": true,
      "competences": [
        {
          "codeCompetence": 7,
          "titre": "Tech. exploitation",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 8,
          "titre": "Tech. postes de travail",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 9,
          "titre": "Tech. réseaux",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 10,
          "titre": "Tech. Help Desk",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 11,
          "titre": "Tech. Téléphonie",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 12,
          "titre": "Tech. Autre",
          "activated": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "codeGroupCompetence": 2,
      "titre": "ETUDES, CONCEPTION, MODELISATION",
      "activated": true,
      "competences": [
        {
          "codeCompetence": 5,
          "titre": "Concepteur UML, Merise, ...",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 13,
          "titre": "Admin Windows",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 14,
          "titre": "Admin Unix",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 15,
          "titre": "Admin Linux",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 16,
          "titre": "Administrateur AS400",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 17,
          "titre": "Administrateur Mainframe IBM",
          "activated": true
        },
        {
          "codeCompetence": 18,
          "titre": "Administrateur Autres Systèmes",
          "activated": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "codeGroupCompetence": 3,
      "titre": "ADMIN SYSTEMES",
      "activated": true,
      "competences": [
        {
          "codeCompetence": 6,
          "titre": "Urbaniste SI",
          "activated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

In order to display this list using the `group by` feature in `ng-options` I created a new array as following :

```
  $scope.competences = [];

    myList.forEach(function(group){
          group.competences.forEach(function(competence){
            $scope.competences.push({
              id : competence.codeCompetence,
              titre : competence.titre,
              group : group.titre
            })
          });
        });
```

and this is how I display my select option :

```
<select ng-model="tipost" 
        ng-options="competence.id as competence.titre group by competence.group for competence in competences track by competence.id">
     </select>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for some reason, which I cant figure out what is it.

So please, how can I solve this ?

Another question : isn't there any other method to use only the first array with the `group by` ?

Thanks in advance.

This is a jsfiddle for my example :

http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/615/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4LLguds/):

A couple of things that I noticed:
I removed the track by clause in your repeat and added a scope vairable $scope.tipost to your controller.

```
<select ng-model="tipost" 
        ng-options="competence.id as competence.titre group by competence.group for competence in competences">
     </select>
```

Controller edits:
You forgot the $scope on the myList variable, now you can use $scope.tipost to assign a preselected option and also retrieve the selected option as well.

```
$scope.tipost = 5;

$scope.myList.forEach(function(group){
          group.competences.forEach(function(competence){
            $scope.competences.push({
              id : competence.codeCompetence,
              titre : competence.titre,
              group : group.titre
            })
          });
        });
```

In this case the console was telling you what was wrong.